# Hide output of cat command

Tags: bash, shell

I have this line of code which I would like to hide its output.

```
Vrs=$(cat  $(echo $line | awk -F"-" '{print "/var/AS-"$2"-"toupper($3)"-"$4}') | grep "YES" | cut -d":" -f5)
```

I have tried to include `&> /dev/null` at the end of the line but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is value in `$line` and what do you want to store in `Vrs`?

Comment: What is tthe output? I'm guessing you get an error because cat is trying to read files that don't exist ?

Comment: Yes, the error is file doesnt exit

Comment: $line is a string. I want to store also a string in Vrs

Comment: Why are you using `cat` here anyway?

Comment: cat opens the file with the name $line

Comment: Use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for assistance

Comment: @João Then still. `awk` accepts file names as input. No need to pipe it via `cat`. Also, think about you variable names. Use `$filename` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rephrase the statement to

```
Vrs=$(echo "$line" | awk -F"-" '{print "/var/AS-"$2"-"toupper($3)"-"$4}' | grep "YES" | cut -d":" -f5)
```

This does the same thing. In  the command is successful, you would get the result stored in `Vrs`. **No output** would be shown in the `stdout`. However, if you expect errors, you could do :

```
Vrs=$(echo "$line" | awk -F"-" '{print "/var/AS-"$2"-"toupper($3)"-"$4}' | grep "YES" | cut -d":" -f5 2>/dev/null)
```

This will suppress the errors and give you an empty `$Vrs`

**Notes:**

I have double quoted `$line` to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: This line is working as expected. I expect this error however I don't want it to show. I have tried to put 2>/dev/null inside the inner and outer $() but it doesnt work

Comment: I do not want to change my code, it is already working.. I have tried to remove the cat but it doesnt work that way

Comment: Thanks you, I will I have to accept your answer, it really hides the output. However I cannot use it since it will create other problems in the following code.

Comment: @João : Please use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) , a great tool to make your scripts better and thanks for accepting the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but your `cat` call looks redundant to me.

```
Vrs=$(echo "$line" | awk -F"-" '{print "/var/AS-"$2"-"toupper($3)"-"$4}' | grep "YES" | cut -d":" -f5)
```

Comment: Sorry pal ! It seems the op was using `awk` correctly. That was my mistake.  you may consider editing the answer. Also `$line` should be double quoted.